# Safest way to get rid of cockroaches found close to dog's house?

Tags: dogs, pest-control

I recently have found that cockroaches are partying next to my dog's house which is outside in the back porch. I want to get rid of them but since my dog likes to sleep in or next to his house don't want him to smell potentially dangerous pesticides.

Is there a safe way to get rid of the cockroaches without risking my dog's health? I found and sprayed outside his house with a natural repellent named 'Fleriana' that claims to be non toxic and that is safe for pets. It seems to do the trick. 2 days have passed and I haven't spotted any roaches.

Any other ideas/suggestions?